# remove last line of each .txt file and import/merge data in R

Tags: r, import, merge, dataframe

I am new to R and can't seem to wrap my head around this. I have multiple .txt files in a folder and would like to import and merge the data. My problem is the last line of each text file. I have tried multiple ways but can't figure out a solution. Thank you in advance for any help. Let me know if any questions with the below.

Text File 1

```
|03/09/2015|Fist Name 1 |Last Name 1|Address 1
|03/09/2015|First Name 2|Last Name 2|Address 2
|2|2|||||||||||
```

Text File 2

```
|03/06/2015|First Name 3|Last Name 3|Address 3
|03/06/2015|First Name 4|Last Name 4|Address 4
|03/06/2015|First Name 5|Last Name 5|Address 5
|3|3|||||||||||
```

Looking for the following outcome

```
V1                   V2                 V3                 V4
03/09/2015      First Name 1          Last Name 1        Address 1
03/09/2015      First Name 2          Last Name 2        Address 2
03/06/2015      First Name 3          Last Name 3        Address 3
03/06/2015      First Name 4          Last Name 4        Address 4
03/06/2015      First Name 5          Last Name 5        Address 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `count.fields()` to help calculate the number for `nrows` in `read.table()`.  You'll have to remove the first column since it will be empty

```
files <- c("x1.txt", "x2.txt")

inList <- lapply(files, function(x) {
    read.table(x, nrows = length(count.fields(x))-1, sep = "|")[-1]
})
do.call(rbind, inList)
#           V2           V3          V4        V5
# 1 03/09/2015 Fist Name 1  Last Name 1 Address 1
# 2 03/09/2015 First Name 2 Last Name 2 Address 2
# 3 03/06/2015 First Name 3 Last Name 3 Address 3
# 4 03/06/2015 First Name 4 Last Name 4 Address 4
# 5 03/06/2015 First Name 5 Last Name 5 Address 5
```

You could add

```
colClasses = c("NULL", "character", "character", "NULL", "character"))
```

to the above `read.table()` call to select only columns 2, 3, and 5 (see comments below)

---

Another approach is to use `fread()`. It makes selecting the columns a bit easier.

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(
    lapply(files, function(x) {
        nr <- length(count.fields(x))-1
        suppressWarnings(
            fread(x, nrows = nr, sep = "|", header = FALSE, drop = c(1, 4))
        )
    })
)
#            V2           V3        V5
# 1: 03/09/2015 Fist Name 1  Address 1
# 2: 03/09/2015 First Name 2 Address 2
# 3: 03/06/2015 First Name 3 Address 3
# 4: 03/06/2015 First Name 4 Address 4
# 5: 03/06/2015 First Name 5 Address 5
```

Note:  This is using data.table [development version 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

---

Where `x1.txt` an d `x2.txt` are

```
writeLines("|03/09/2015|Fist Name 1 |Last Name 1|Address 1
|03/09/2015|First Name 2|Last Name 2|Address 2
|2|2|||||||||||", "x1.txt")

writeLines("|03/06/2015|First Name 3|Last Name 3|Address 3
|03/06/2015|First Name 4|Last Name 4|Address 4
|03/06/2015|First Name 5|Last Name 5|Address 5
|3|3|||||||||||", "x2.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you Richard. I think this should work. Let's suppose in my real data,  in addition to remove the 1st column (like you did), is there a way to also remove the 4th column. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes,  instead of `[-1]` at the end of `read.table()` you can put `[-c(1, 4)]`

Comment: @JimmyDeBlasio - I've also added another possibility with `fread()`

Comment: I get the following error when using fread method ---- Error in fread(x, nrows = nr, sep = "|", header = FALSE, drop = c(1, 4)) : 
  Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch='|'

Comment: Hmm,  I'm not quite sure about that message.  Does it work when you run `read.table()` with the `colClasses` argument?

Comment: @JimmyDeBlasio, I'd suggest installing [1.9.5, devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) and trying it out, as quite a few things have been fixed w.r.t. `fread()`. If it still doesn't fix, it'd be great to have a minimal example file that produces the error so that we can look at the issue and fix it.

Comment: @Arun I get a new error after installation "showProgress must be 0 or 1, currently"

Comment: @JimmyDeBlasio could you please link to the file you're getting an error? I can't do much without testing it myself.

Comment: @JimmyDeBlasio, reads fine for me. Try uninstalling and reinstalling `v1.9.5`.